# UDP connection / android user

Tags: android, udp, user-permissions

I want to mention that this is a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate and I never got ANY answer at all.I have had this problem for over 2 months and meanwhile I had to move on with the project and ignore the problem, but I am at the point where I can no longer move ahead without solving this.

So, I have an UDP connection that looks like this:

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
         public void run() {


    try {
     if(host != null){
         byte [] data = "lista_categorii".getBytes();
         byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

         host = InetAddress.getByName(//IPGOESHERE;
         socket = new DatagramSocket(55901);


         DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, host, 55901);             
         socket.send(packet);
         socket.setSoTimeout(1000);


         /*
         packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
         socket.receive(packet);    
         //String modifiedSentence = new String(packet.getData()); 
         modifiedSentence = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());*/

     }

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    if(socket != null){
        socket.close();
    }
}
         }
     };
```

Everything works fine until I press the button that calls the code that I just linked.Once I do that, I get this Hell-spawned error:

```
07-04 15:11:44.199: E/DatabaseUtils(2344): Writing exception to parcel
07-04 15:11:44.199: E/DatabaseUtils(2344): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
07-04 15:11:44.199: E/DatabaseUtils(2344):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
07-04 15:11:44.199: E/DatabaseUtils(2344):  at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
07-04 15:11:44.199: E/DatabaseUtils(2344):  at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
07-04 15:11:44.199: E/DatabaseUtils(2344):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
07-04 15:11:44.199: E/DatabaseUtils(2344):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
07-04 15:11:44.199: E/DatabaseUtils(2344):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
07-04 15:11:44.199: E/DatabaseUtils(2344):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

My Android Manifest looks like this(I am sure people will ask so yea...):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.applicatierestaurant"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.restaurant.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.restaurant.main.Categories" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.restaurant.main.Produse" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.restaurant.main.ScreenComanda" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.restaurant.main.OfertaZilei" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.restaurant.main.CeAmComandat" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If any other information is needed, let me know and I will be with you right away.

NOTE: I am testing it on a Samsung Galaxy S3.